# Validatation error "Value Error : background-position Too many values or values are not" How to solve?

Tags: xhtml, w3c, w3c-validation, css

Why is the validation returning this error. How to resolve it?

```
ul#navigation li#navigation-3 a.current
```

> Value Error : background-position  Too
>   many values or values are not
>   recognized : -164px -164px -36px 
>   -164px -164px -36px

This is the error screen.

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/321632/110323115458-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/321632/110323115458-My-Desktop.png)

CSS

```
ul#navigation { height: 36px; left: 300px; list-style-image: none; list-style-position: outside; list-style-type: none; position: relative; top: 74px; width: 603px; }

ul#navigation li { display: inline; }

ul#navigation li a { height: 36px; float: left; text-decoration: none;  }

ul#navigation li a:link, ul#navigation li a:visited {font-family:Arial; color:#595959; font-size:1.1em; font-weight:bold }

ul#navigation li a:hover, ul#navigation li a:active {color:#404040}

ul#navigation li a span { display:block;
float:left;
padding-left:8px;
padding-top:14px;}

ul#navigation li#navigation-1 a { width: 53px; background: url(../images/menu-sprite.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0; }


ul#navigation li#navigation-1 a:active, ul#navigation li#navigation-1 a:hover { background-position: 0px -36px; }

ul#navigation li#navigation-1 a.current { background-position: 0px 0px -36px; }

ul#navigation li#navigation-2 a { width: 111px; background: url(../images/menu-sprite.jpg) no-repeat -53px 0; }

ul#navigation li#navigation-2 a:active, ul#navigation li#navigation-2 a:hover { background-position: -53px -36px; }

ul#navigation li#navigation-2 a.current { background-position: -53px -53px -36px; }

ul#navigation li#navigation-3 a { width: 78px; background: url(../images/menu-sprite.jpg) no-repeat -164px 0; }

ul#navigation li#navigation-3 a:active, ul#navigation li#navigation-3 a:hover { background-position: -164px -36px; }

ul#navigation li#navigation-3 a.current { background-position: -164px -164px -36px; }

ul#navigation li#navigation-4 a { width: 100px; background: url(../images/menu-sprite.jpg) no-repeat -242px 0; }

ul#navigation li#navigation-4 a:active, ul#navigation li#navigation-4 a:hover { background-position: -242px -36px; }

ul#navigation li#navigation-4 a.current { background-position: -242px -242px -36px; }

ul#navigation li#navigation-5 a { width: 88px; background: url(../images/menu-sprite.jpg) no-repeat -342px 0; }

ul#navigation li#navigation-5 a:active, ul#navigation li#navigation-5 a:hover { background-position: -342px -36px; }

ul#navigation li#navigation-5 a.current { background-position: -342px -342px -36px; }

ul#navigation li#navigation-6 a { width: 96px; background: url(../images/menu-sprite.jpg) no-repeat -430px 0; }

ul#navigation li#navigation-6 a:active, ul#navigation li#navigation-6 a:hover { background-position: -430px -36px; }

ul#navigation li#navigation-6 a.current { background-position: -430px -430px -36px; }

ul#navigation li#navigation-7 a { width: 77px; background: url(../images/menu-sprite.jpg) no-repeat -526px 0; }

ul#navigation li#navigation-7 a:active, ul#navigation li#navigation-7 a:hover { background-position: -526px -36px; }

ul#navigation li#navigation-7 a.current { background-position: -526px -526px -36px; }
```

Comment: background-position: left-value top-value; thats how it works, and thats what the W3C validation tells you :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this:

```
ul#navigation li#navigation-3 a.current { background-position: -164px -164px -36px; }
```

There are only two values needed to position a background, get rid of one and it should validate.

**Update**: you have this on all of your `current` selectors, remove the third value from all and it will be fine.

Comment: I made this code using this tool http://lab.mattvarone.com/navbar/ code is working fine but giving validation error.

Comment: Web pages are still in 2D. ;-)

Comment: Even so, the code is wrong, remove one of the values and it should validate. Not every tool is perfect, you'll always have to go over and check generated codes yourself :) Haha @Gumbo!

Comment: So you used a tool which generated broken code that (some) browsers are capable of error correcting for. Big whoop. The code is still wrong. If "it works in my browser" was all we needed, we wouldn't bother with validators.

Comment: @David Dorward: But you only see a 2D projection of that model.

Answer (score 1):

`Background-position` gets 2 values not 3.
[See here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-position.asp)